# How do I link two forms in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

My teacher gave us an assignment to link two forms together where one form is an admin form where u can put things and delete things together and another form is an user form where they can only view it. My question is I want to do a video input format and I can only embed my videos on form 1 but it wont show on form 2  can anyone please help.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. Please edit your question and tag the technologies you’re using, as well as a language. Take the [tour] and read the [help] also. Otherwise your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you can use method and redirect to your forms.

Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx"); on login page maybe

and in your pages you can code for the functionalities.